# LDAP bind to DC in another forest after bind to its domain results in LDAP error 82

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap, kerberos

I encountered a strange error when trying to bind to a specific DC using the `LdapConnection` class. I managed to strip down the code to the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cred = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domainFQDN");
    try
    {
        var ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("domain1.test.local", 389, false, false), cred, AuthType.Kerberos);
        ldapConnection.Bind();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected 1");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    try
    {
        var ldapConnection2 = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("dc1.domain1.test.local", 389, true, false), cred, AuthType.Kerberos);
        ldapConnection2.Bind();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected 2");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The output of this program is consistently:

```
Connected 1
System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: A local error occurred.
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.BindHelper(NetworkCredential newCredential, Boolean needSetCredential)
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.Bind()
```

The only difference between the calls is that in the first connection I use the domain FQDN in the `LdapDirectoryIdentifier`, while in the second connection I use the exact DC address. Of course, I verified that the first connection goes to the same DC as the second one.

The error only occurs when I specify `AuthType.Kerberos` for the authentication method. The error occurs always when I try to connect to a domain in a different forest, and only sometimes when I connect to a DC in the local forest.

I can probably work around the error by using the domain name twice, but then I won't ensure stickiness once I get a connection to a specific DC.

How can I make sure that the second connection goes to the same DC without getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

> The error only occurs when I specify AuthType.Kerberos for the authentication method.

Your issue is the Kerberos authentication then.

From a command line, try (use the short name of the DC, not the FQDN):

```
setspn dc1
```

There should be a bunch in that list, but I think the problem one here would be "ldap/dc1.domain1.test.local/domain1.test.local". Do you see that in the list?

If not, you can add it. As a domain admin, use this from the command line:

```
setspn -a ldap/dc1.domain1.test.local/domain1.test.local dc1
```

More details here, although the missing SPN it talks about in that article is one with a GUID. The list at the bottom shows what the list of SPNs should look like: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/308111/a-missing-service-principal-name-may-prevent-domain-controllers-from-r

If that SPN is already listed, then you can turn on Kerberos logging by following the instructions here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/262177/how-to-enable-kerberos-event-logging

Once logging is enabled, Kerberos errors will show up in the System event log. It'll give you a better idea why it's failing.

Comment: The spn is set correctly. I've enabled the Kerberos log and all I can see are regular KDC_ERR_PREAUTH_REQUIRED. I did discover, however, that the problem mostly exists when I try to connect to DCs in other forests.